# Making to_json much more efficient for nested objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, mongoid

Consider a typical relational structure:

```
Answer has many comments. comments belongs to a user, and have many likers

answers.to_json(:include => {:comments => {:include => :user, :likers}})
```

If i call to_json , it will perform the database retrievals one by one for individual user in individual comments.

The much more efficient solution would be to put the required ids for each type in an array, do 3 database calls to retrieve them, put it into a hash, and construct the json according to the hash.

This seems like a pretty common use case. I am thinking of writing my own recursive function for this, but if anyone can point me to something that has already been done, that will be great!

** i am using mongoid / mongodb, i am not sure if it works the same way in active record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can try mongoid eager loading,  then you can query mongo just like AR eager loading

```
 Answer.includes(:comments, :likers)
```

The patch is still not included in the mongoid master branch, but you can  download it as a independednt gem from [here](https://github.com/flyerhzm/mongoid-eager-loading)

Read this [pull request](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/pull/391) for more info